# Can i have different SQL alias's for newly added server in SharePoint farm?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

Lets say i have 4 server's in my SharePoint farm. All the servers in the farm are configured to use a SQL alias "ProdEnv". If i want to add a 5th server in the farm, can i have a different SQL alias just for this new server? Lets say "ProdEnvDR"

Comment: are you adding SharePoint Server or SQL Server?

Comment: I am adding SharePoint server to the farm

Answer (score 0):

All servers must use the same alias(es) in the farm. A DR environment should be a separate farm, not the same farm.

Answer (score 0):

All SharePoint Server in the farm should use same Alias. because they have to communicate to Config DB and Service dbs if you use different alias for on server then it will break the farm.

Comment: It won't break the farm. That particular farm member will not be able to join the existing farm or if changed after the fact, won't be able to communicate with the farm.

Comment: Thanks. When i run the config wizard, this is the error i get "Failed to connect to the existing server farm located at the specified database server and database name. The database name is not a valid configuration database."

Comment: make sure you are running the config wizard under the farm admin / install account which has right permission on the Config db, also make sure you can connect to SQL server without any firewall etc

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint farm, alias concept is relevant only with SQL server... what happens in SQL server? There might be multiple SQL servers for SharePoint that will be mapped and connected with the **SQL availability group listener** for the server stability and finally with this listener name **SQL alias** name is mapped.

**Why does the SharePoint server connect to fail in SharePoint config database while running the wizard?**

There could be multiple scenarios for this -

- First, we need to check network port connectivity between the new
  SharePoint server what you are trying to add and the SQL server.
- Check whether if any firewall is blocking to access the SQL server, the best way to handle this, talk to your network team, they will assist you.
- Make sure TCP **1433, 32843, 32844** is opened in the new SharePoint server.
- Finally, verify that the **SharePoint_config** database is connected both the primary availability group and secondary availability group because when you are running the wizard and passing the **alias name** we are not directly talking to SharePoint server, it is going through some layers of connectivities, so the connectivity has to pass through.

For the various TCP/IP Port refer to the below article:

[SharePoint 2016 – TCP/IP Ports](https://blogit.create.pt/fabiocarvalho/2017/02/14/sharepoint-2016-tcpip-ports/)

For the SharePoint server cannot connect to the SQL database, refer to the below article:

[SharePoint Troubleshooting: Cannot connect to database master at SQL Server](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36615.sharepoint-troubleshooting-cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server.aspx)